# C++/CLI circular reference issue with CLI Classes

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I am having an issue with two classes that reference each other. I have attempted to use an interface to resolve the issue, but run into other problems such as class re-definition. I am just not sure how to do this properly.

here is an example of what I have going on. Note: I have taken out all the extra properties and methods that are not actually affecting this issue.  How can I redo these without causing class re-definitions and without the circular reference. If you can, please use this example as a template for a correct layout of the statements.

```
// componentClass.h
//#include "controlClass.h" - Would cause a circular reference
namespace test
{
    //component class
    public ref class componentClass sealed : Component
    {
    internal:
        componentClass(controlClass ^control);
    private:
        controlClass ^_control;
    };
}

// controlClass.h
#include "componentClass.h";
namespace test
{
    //control class
    public ref class controlClass: Control
    {
    public:
        controlClass();
    private:
        componentClass ^_componentClass;
    };
}

// controlClass.cpp
#include "controlClass.h"
controlClass::controlClass()
{
    _componentClass = gcnew componentClass(this);
}

// componentClass.cpp
#include "componentClass.h"
componentClass::componentClass(controlClass ^control)
{
    _control = control;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the easiest way to resolve this issue is to put both class declarations inside of one header file, and forward-declare the second one.  For example:

```
namespace test
{
    // Forward declaration of controlClass
    ref class controlClass;

    //component class
    public ref class componentClass sealed : Component
    {
    internal:
        componentClass(controlClass ^control);
    private:
        controlClass ^_control;
    };

    //control class
    public ref class controlClass: Control
    {
    public:
        controlClass();
    private:
        componentClass ^_componentClass;
    };
}
```

It's *possible* to accomplish this with multiple header files, but there are caveats and complexities that are eliminated by using a single header file.

You can continue to provide the implementation of each class in a different source file without problems.

Comment: Thanks, that is EXACTLY what I was looking for. I knew about forward referencing, but it escaped me to include the componentClass's declarations in the same include file as the controlClass's declarations.